# Finding which timetamps from a list sit between a date-range in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of timestamps (df1), and a larger list of timestamps (ls1).

I'm looking to filter out any rows from df1 who's start and end times don't *encompass* any value from ls1.

To put it another way, if any value from ls1 is *between* a start_time and end_time value from df1, then keep that row in df1.

The crucial problem I can't get past is that these are not the same length, so comparing them is not working. Here is what I have so far.

The setup:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['2019-02-20 04:40','2019-02-20 19:35'],
                   ['2019-03-25 03:40','2019-03-25 22:35'],
                   ['2019-05-10 08:00','2019-05-11 02:55'],
                   ['2019-05-16 01:00','2019-05-17 00:55'],
                   ['2019-05-22 02:25','2019-05-22 19:20'],
                   ['2019-06-27 04:05','2019-06-27 22:00']], 
                   columns = ['start_time', 'finish_time']).apply(pd.to_datetime)
df1['data'] = np.random.rand(len(df1)) # adding for aesthetics

ls1 = ['2019-02-01 00:05', '2019-02-14 15:50', '2019-03-04 11:00', 
       '2019-03-15 03:25', '2019-03-29 05:00', '2019-04-11 00:10',
       '2019-04-26 13:35', '2019-05-04 12:45', '2019-05-10 16:45', 
       '2019-05-10 16:50', '2019-05-10 17:45', '2019-05-10 18:25',
       '2019-05-12 05:55', '2019-05-15 11:00', '2019-05-18 07:20', 
       '2019-06-02 12:10', '2019-06-14 19:30', '2019-06-21 03:00']
ls1 = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(ls1))
```

What I've tried:

```
df1.loc[(df1.start_time < ls1.values) & (df1.finish_time > ls1.values)]
```

and

```
ls1.between(df1.start_time.values,df1.finish_time.values, inclusive=False)
```

Both of these give: `ValueError: Lengths must match`

The desired result is to identify the items from ls1 that meet the criteria:

```
2019-05-10 16:45:00
2019-05-10 16:50:00
2019-05-10 17:45:00
2019-05-10 18:25:00
```

And then use that to filter df1 to only the relevant row:

```
           start_time         finish_time     data
2 2019-05-10 08:00:00 2019-05-11 02:55:00 0.691208
```

I'm guessing Pandas [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) function would be ideal if it wasn't looking for explicit matches?

Any help would be appreciated, as it's a very large dataset and nested for-loops just aren't feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had one row only and ls1 as a list, the following function would do:

```
def to_keep(row):
    global ls1
    start = row['start_time']
    end = row['end_time']
    return any(start <= time <= end for time in ls1)
```

Now let us create a mask that will be True if we want to keep the row of the dataframe and False otherwise.

```
mask = df1[['start_time', 'end_time']].apply(to_keep, axis=1)
```

Finally, we can keep only the entries needed:

```
df1 = df1[mask]
```

Comment: Sorry, just a follow up question, i can't seem to identify which items from ls1 caused the match. The use of any() is very cool for a boolean mask, but would you know how i can find the matching items from ls1?

Comment: Once you deleted the unnecessary rows, you are guaranteed that at least one timestamp will do. Now you can determine which one by creating additional column.

Comment: ```
def to_keep2(row):
    global ls1
    start = row['start_time']
    end = row['end_time']
    return [time for time in ls1 if start <= time <= end]
```

Comment: Finally, create a new column: `df['which_timestamp']=df[['start_time', 'end_time']].apply(to_keep2)`

Comment: I see. I wasn't thinking in terms of a 2-step process, thank you again!